# font size in Google Maps viewed through mobile web browsers (iphone and android) is too small

Tags: google-maps

I created a mobile web site that uses Google Maps. However, the font-size of everything on the map is way too small for a mobile device. Is there any way to increase it?

I already tried using webkit's proprietary text size adjust property and it didn't work:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:200%;
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried the CSS transform solution (thanks for the idea, Jimmy!) but I ran into a problem. The "transform" doesn't affect the scaling of the touch input. So when you try to zoom or drag the map, you get very disconcerting effects!

I ended up implementing a solution I found here:
http://sunpig.com/martin/archives/2012/03/18/goldilocks-and-the-three-device-pixel-ratios.html

Basically the article explores the difference between physical pixels and CSS "pixels". There is a scale factor between the two. Its default value on most mobile browsers seems to be the reason why you often see pages designed for desktops looking very "zoomed out" with tiny text on a phone. And it also seems to cause unreadable Google Maps!

My problems went away when I added this HTML snippet into my "head" section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Why hasn't this answer been accepted? Just saved me a lot of frustration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to increase the font size is to magnify the div containing the maps. This will result in a somewhat blurry map render, and loss of controls because of the repositioning of the view. Use CSS transform property with a value of scale(2) to zoom 200%. Not a very nice solution, but it's all I can think of.